# comparing list of maps in java and printing result in table

Tags: java, list, maps

[image: Looking for this output]
I have two list of maps.

```
 List1=[{1=one,2=two},{1=three,2=two}]
 List2=[{1=one,2=twoss},{1=three,2=twoss}]
```

I am trying to compare maps in lists and get it in table form html. Though I am unable to get desired html format. Keys in all maps will be same but values can be different and trying to get keys in header and values beneath it comparing from screen and database, if they match the it will be wrapped in green else red. So screen has table with two rows & header. Database also has two rows and header. Storing this values in list of maps and comparing them.

```
public String compare(List<Map<String, Object>> list1, List<Map<String, Object>> list2) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder tbe = new StringBuilder();
    String col = "";
    String screen = "";
    String db = "";
    if (list1.size() = list2.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, Object> a = list1.get(i);
            Map<String, Object> b = list2.get(i);
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> ent : a.entrySet()) {
                col = col + "<th>" + entry.getKey() + "</th>";
                String k = ent.getKey();
                Object o1 = entry.getValue();
                if (o1.equals(b.get(key))) {
                    screen = screen + "<td bgcolor=green>" + o1 + "</td>";
                    db = db + "<td bgcolor=green>" + b.get(entry.getKey()) + "</td>";
                } else {
                    screen = screen + "<td bgcolor=red>" + o1 + "</td>";
                    db = db + "<td bgcolor=red>" + b.get(entry.getKey()) + "</td>";
                }

            }
            tbe.append("<tr><th>col</th>" + col + "</tr>");
            tbe.append("<tr><th>screen</th>" + screen + "</tr>");
            tbe.append("<tr><th>db</th>" + db + "</tr>");
            tbe.append("</table></html>");
            String tbel = tbe.toString();
            system.out.println(tbel);
            return tbel;
        }
    }
}
```

Desired o/p i am looking for --column headers get printed just once, whereas now I am getting repeated html tables.

Comment: And be clear about what you're trying to do and why it isn't working.

Comment: @SamOrozco have attached image on what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static String compare(List<Map<String, Object>> list1, List<Map<String, Object>> list2) {
        StringBuilder tbe = new StringBuilder();
        String col = "";
        String screen = "";
        String db = "";
        if (list1.size() == list2.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
                Map<String, Object> a = list1.get(i);
                Map<String, Object> b = list2.get(i);
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> ent : a.entrySet()) {
                    col = col + "<th>" + ent.getKey() + "</th>";
                    String key = ent.getKey();
                    Object o1 = ent.getValue();
                    if (o1.equals(b.get(key))) {
                        screen = screen + "<td bgcolor=green>" + o1 + "</td>";
                        db = db + "<td bgcolor=green>" + b.get(ent.getKey()) + "</td>";
                    } else {
                        screen = screen + "<td bgcolor=red>" + o1 + "</td>";
                        db = db + "<td bgcolor=red>" + b.get(ent.getKey()) + "</td>";
                    }

                }
                tbe.append("<tr><th>col</th>" + col + "</tr>");
                tbe.append("<tr><th>screen</th>" + screen + "</tr>");
                tbe.append("<tr><th>db</th>" + db + "</tr>");
                tbe.append("</table></html>");
            }
        }
        return tbe.toString();
    }
```

o/p:

```
<tr>
    <th>col</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>screen</th>
    <td bgcolor=red>One</td>
    <td bgcolor=red>Two</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>db</th>
    <td bgcolor=red>M2One</td>
    <td bgcolor=red>M2Two</td>
</tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Fixing compile time errors in your code is giving me this output. Is this what you are expecting?